# What role does 'in' take in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> Father: “It may not be exactly the car you want but..”
>  Daughter:
>   “It’ll be rubbish, some old wreck that I’ll look totally stupid
>   **in**.”
>  (BBC, [The Archers](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/archers), 2013-04-26 Friday, 8’55”~9’01”)

Does the ‘in’ make adverbial in the text, a supplementive as an adjective, or something else?

[image]
source: The Lexicogrammar of Adjectives: A Systemic Functional Approach to Lexis, p201)

Comment: It's just a preposition that's been stranded by relative clause formation. _I'll look totally stupid in the wreck_ is the underlying clause before it becomes a relative clause modifying _some old wreck_. She could also have said _in which I'll look totally stupid_, but that falutes too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very formal traditional English, this sentence would be written:

> It will be a terrible automobile, some old wreck **in which** I will look totally stupid.

Contemporary English disfavors using the formal prepositional phrase **in which** with its relative pronoun **which**: it replaces **which** with **that** and separates the preposition by putting it at the end of the sentence. Back in the day (18th-19th-20th centuries), grammarians and English teachers used to teach native Anglophones that it was incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition, but that wasn't something we could continue to believe in. Native speakers have always spoken sentences that end with prepositions. It's natural English syntax.

*Something **in which** I will look totally stupid* sounds stilted and awkward to the native Anglophone's ear. *Something I'll look totally stupid **in*** sounds normal. This is merely a prepositional phrase reordered so that the preposition is now a post-sentence element.

All prepositions are tossed into the trashcan (words we don't really know how to properly label in English, so we borrow the label from Latin) of *adverbs*. Just call it a ["sentence-ending *preposition*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), as is **put** in the famous sentence *[This is something up with which I will not put](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/winstonchu122535.html)*.

Answer (score 2):

*In* heads a prepositional phrase constituting an adverbial of location within a relative clause headed by *that*:

> I will look totally stupid ***in it*** >>> ***that*** I will look totally stupid ***in _***

If the relative pronoun were *that* instead of *which*, the preposition could be 'pied-piped' instead of 'stranded':

> ***in which*** I will look totally stupid

But this is not permitted with *that*.

Stranding a preposition in this manner was once frowned on by many stylists, but this prejudice is gradually disappearing. Stranding has always been common in colloquial registers (although recent corpus studies* suggest that it is not nearly so common as was once thought).

* Johansson and Geisler, "Pied Piping in Spoken English", in Renouf, *Explorations in Corpus Linguistics*, 1998; Hoffman, "Variable vs. categorical effects: Preposition pied piping and stranding in British English relative clauses", *Journal of English Linguistics*, 2005; Hoffman, *Preposition Placement in English*, 2011.